# How to do yum backup and restore?

Tags: centos, yum

Is there a way to make a backup of package that will be change while yum update? For example when I do yum update lighttpd is there a way to backup and restore lighttpd if yum update will be unsuccessful or it will result in unsuspected errors or bugs?

Comment: I think you may have just spent 150 bounty on a question that would otherwise have been closed as off-topic....

Comment: @skaffman Do you think it's better question for serverfault? I'm not sure. Maybe you are right. But still need an answer

Comment: Perhaps you could also post the question to serverfault. Then, it's a race. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using RPM before 4.6.0 ([it's removed in newer versions](http://www.rpm.org/wiki/Releases/4.6.0#Removedfeatures)), you can use `rpm --rollback` mechanism like [in this old tutorial](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2006/01/rpm_rollback_in_fedora_core_45.html) or in [a more complete article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7034) with some functionality explanation. The --rollback feature is an *automatic* solution that was removed since it isn't reliable.

You can have a *manual* solution, keeping a list of all the packages **before** the yum update and reinstall needed old rpms possibly using --oldpackage like `rpm -Uvh --oldpackage foo-1-1.i386.rpm`:

To get a list of all installed packages, sorted by installation time:

```
rpm -q -a --queryformat '%{INSTALLTIME} %{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}\n' | sort -n
```

([Source](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Fedora/2005-07/4771.html))

If you're using Fedora, here is an official guide to upgrade the system using the installer with an example of how to create [a list of system current installed packages](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Installation_Guide/sn-upgrade-tree-x86.html) and how to [restore most of old software after an upgrade](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Installation_Guide/sn-finishing-upgrade.html).

If you want a *generic* approach to get a list of installed software (not only rpm based), you can follow [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-get-list-installed-software-reinstallation-restore.html) as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a repo. that keeps all old versions around, you can just do "yum downgrade lighttpd" (and with newer yum's "yum history undo"). If you aren't, then you can keep a local copy of the old rpm and use "yum downgrade lighttpd*.rpm" (although that is trickier).
It's possible that some problems won't be fixed by this, but those should be very rare and downgrade is unlikely to change anything else as a side effect.

Very recently a plugin "yum-plugin-fs-snapshot" has been created, which will automatically take an FS snapshot (btrfs, or LVM) before doing an upgrade ... thus. you can then just rollback to the snapshot. This is a *big* change though, so I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I use [etckeeper](http://joey.kitenet.net/code/etckeeper/) to track changes of files under `/etc`. etckeeper puts `/etc` under version control (it supports multiple version control systems, including Git, Mercurial and Bazaar) and integrates with the package management systems of a number of Linux distros (APT, YUM, Pacman).

If something bad happens during an upgrade or so, I can rollback anything.